# unable to make module-based jar with javapackager

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, javapackager

I am new to javapackager and Java 9, and am working through the examples in the [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javapackager.html#sthref241) reference, with the first example shown below:

> Example 1 - Using the -createjar Command
>
> ```
> javapackager -createjar -appclass package.ClassName
>   -srcdir classes -outdir out -outfile outjar -v
>
> Packages the contents of the classes directory to outjar.jar, 
> sets the application class to package.ClassName.
> ```

I am able to make the jar file (tcdmod.jar) without an error messages. But I get an error when I try to execute the jar with the normal command:

```
java -jar tcdmod.jar
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class 
>   moduleTCD.com.adonax.tanpura.TCDLaunch
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/adonax/tanpura/TCDLaunch 
>   (wrong name: moduleTCD/com/adonax/tanpura/TCDLaunch)

Command used for making the jar:

```
javapackager -createjar -appclass moduleTCD/com.adonax.tanpura.TCDLaunch
-srcdir compiled -outdir outex1 -outfile tcdmod -v
```

Folder for compiled:

```
compiled/moduleTCD/com/adonax/tanpura/ [compiled classes here and below]
compiled/moduleTCD/module-info.class
```

The manifest in the jar shows:

```
Main-Class: moduleTCD/com.adonax.tanpura.TCDLaunch
```

Things I've tried so far to solve this:

- I could not tell from documentation if I specified the -appclass parameter correctly. Documentation defines -appclass as follows: "Qualified name of the application class to be executed." But I don't see any indication of what is meant by "qualified". I tried a few different names that seemed plausible. Is the form with the module name that I used correct?
- I created a second "compiled" directory in which the module was simply omitted from the project, and retried the command using that for my -srcdir. The resulting jar file worked fine in that case.
- I verified that I could run the program from the command line using the compiled source (from the "compiled" folder):

  java -p . -m moduleTCD/com.adonax.tanpura.TCDLaunch

Any thoughts? 
In order to make a self-contained exe package (the main goal), I need to have a module-based jar file, if I am reading the documentation correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out by taking a closer look at the syntax for the jar command. (Something I never did in the past thanks to Eclipse IDE handling this automatically.)

Here is what I discovered and fixed.

1)
The **-appclass** argument should be the package location of the main, and does not include the module in which the package resides.

Thus, I changed the argument from "moduleTCD/com.adonax.tanpura.TCDLaunch" to "com.adonax.tanpura.TCDLaunch".

2) The **-srcdir** argument should be the module folder (containing module-info.class). Thus, I changed the argument from "compiled" to "compiled/src/moduleTCD".

So, for my particular situation (only one module, no additional jars or libraries to link up), the following command (as a single line) worked correctly.

```
javapackager -createjar -appclass com.adonax.tanpura.TCDLaunch -srcdir
compiled/src/moduleTCD -outdir outex1 -outfile tcdmod -v
```

Here is the (single line) jar command that also works.

```
jar -cfe outex1.tcdmod.jar com.adonax.tanpura.TCDLaunch -C 
compiled/src/moduleTCD .
```